# Get a key from a javascript array when array has only 1 element

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I need to get the key (string) from an javascript Object, I use:

```
for (var key in foo) {
    console.log(key)
}
```

This will log all the key strings in the console.

However what if there is only 1 entry in the array? (so only 1 key)

I can't find how to handle that?

The above `for` works but not sure if it's needed when there is only 1 element?

I don't want to log the object associated, I want to log the string of the key itself.

On an object `{ fruit : 'apple' }` I want to log the string `"fruit"`

So considering `var foodType = { fruit : 'apple' , meat: 'beef' , fruit : 'pear' }`

And also if there is only one element

```
foodType = { fruit : 'apple' }
```

How do I log that?

Comment: Ehhhh ... I read the question 3 times and I still don't know whats asked.

Comment: I don't think it's key. First, because JS got only integers as keys in arrays. Second, because you are getting values, not keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider something like:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // "foo"
var value = obj[key]; // "bar"
```

Or in one line:

```
var value = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; // "bar"
```

Comment: +1 Pretty good, even if the one-liner is pretty cryptic for a junior dev like myself :|

Comment: I think it's along the right track, but value doesn't equal the key, it equals the object {key : value}  I want value = key(string) so value should = 'key'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't want to log the object associated, I want to log the string of the key itself. { 'fruit' : 'apple' }  I want to log the string 'fruit'

Comment: Then just use `Object.keys(obj)[0]`.

Comment: I don't understand. `var obj = { foo: "bar" }; console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);` gives "foo". Does your object have Number-like properties, like: `obj = { 0: "bar" };`?

Comment: No, it has string keys

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
var key = Object.keys(foo).pop();
```

Comment: Whats the difference if `foo` has 1 or 100 properties ?

Comment: @jAndy This might be slower `:)` Otherwise it is just a way to get the last key in one line, exactly what the OP wants to get instead of `for (var key in foo) break;`.